# How to Map data from JSON Array of Objects to My List

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest

I am unable to unable to Map to the data .

I am sending the following JSON to map to my List Object

```
[{
    "Student": {
        "name": "Ram"
    },
    "Address": {
        "text": "6666 SE 3301"

    }
}]
```

This is Student class

```
@Data
public class Student {

        private String name;

}
```

This is Address class

```
@Data
public class Address {

    private String text;

}
```

This is AllDetails class

```
@Data
public class AllDetails {

    private Student student;
    private Address text;
}
```

This is the way i am accepting data

```
@PostMapping(value = AllDetails)
    public @ResponseBody String maptoObj(@RequestBody List<AllDetails> details) throws Exception {


        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        List<AllDetails> allDet = objectMapper.readValue(details,  AllDetails[].class);

        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This should work.

```
public class AllDetails {
    @JsonProperty("Student")
    private Student student;
    @JsonProperty("Address")
    private Address address;
}
```

Variable name you are using: student and address.
But in Json it is Student and Address.

use `@JsonProperty` to tell jackson what is the variable name in json it should look for

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines

```
...
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
List<AllDetails> allDet = objectMapper.readValue(details, new TypeReference<>() {
        });
...



@Data
class AllDetails {
    @JsonAlias("Student")
    private Student student;
    @JsonAlias("Address")
    private Address address;

}

@Data
class Student {

    private String name;
}

@Data
class Address {

    private String text;

}
```